# Horror movie: friends in a yacht get capsized, drift to an island with killers

Tags: story-identification, horror

What is the title of this movie? I think it's set somewhere in Europe. There were a group of friends in a yacht in the middle of the sea when a strong storm capsized their boat. Some managed to survive and drifted to an island with small village. Apparently, they are killers and skin their preys and wear them. There is also a beautiful lady with lower limbs of an octopus tentacles. She fell in love with the male main character. In the end, that character is one of them - the sea creatures.

Comment: Closed as a duplicate since the wording is almost word-for-word the same as the question that got asked and answered two days ago. If you lost the credentials to your earlier account, please follow [these instructions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to retrieve them and formally accept (or deny) the answer.

Comment: probably the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/243840/original-sci-fi-movie-where-an-innkeeper-has-gills (which is newer but has an accepted answer)